# p is an odd prime that does not divide $b(b^2-1)$, show that 2 can divide $b^p+b$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose $b>1$ and p is an odd prime that does not divide $b(b^2-1)$, show that 2 can divide $b^p+b$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$b^p + b = b(b^{p-1}-1)$$
If $b$ is even, we are done. If $b$ is odd, $b^{p-1}$ is odd for any integer $p>1$, so $(b^{p-1}-1)$ is even.
You don't even need the original extra restriction on $p$ or $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Take an odd $b$. Then $b^p$ is also odd, and $b^p+b$ is even, therefore
$$
2 | (b^p+b).
$$
(For an even $b$, the conclusion is immediate.)